# Flex Mobile, which map to use for Android and iOS

Tags: android, apache-flex, ios5, maps, flex4.6

I have been developing flex applications for a while now and at last i got a major customer who needs a mobile application using maps. After a bit of researching i found out that all the flash apis are oute of the question for iOS so it seems there's no way to use google maps and yahoo maps for flex. Does anyone have any advices about which maps to use? what would you recomend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a clear enough article about:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/mobile-mapping-app-arcgis.html

Or you can try to go with gMaps or something like it, be sure you know your goals and budget.

Comment: i will give it a try but most likely there is going t be the same problem as in gmaps. the api makes request for swf which are not loaded in the iOS.

Comment: Hi there. Actually, not exactly as you thought. Take a look on these:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arcgis/id379687930?mt=8
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/mobile-mapping-app-arcgis.html
and live demo:
http://spatiallyadjusted.com/2011/08/15/esri-arcgis-flex-api-to-ipad-app/

Comment: Thanx for your time and the information :) im giving it a try to see how it will work out. I also found mapquest which seems to work hopefully there wont be a problem as with google maps for flex.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to reply, but...
You may also visit [OpenScales](http://www.openscales.org). This map client is based on the old Modest Maps with new features. According to the documents you can use it in mobile apps but practically, it's not that easy. There are several threads in the OpenScales' google group about how to make it available on mobile devices.

There is also a branch provided by Web Map Solutions: http://www.webmapsolutions.com/mobile-gis-openscales

And last but not least, take a look at this too: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash-mobile